# sql query to convert row into column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

i have a table with schema like below image

```
             id     empcode      question      answer     date
             1        011        ur name?      abcd         20/10/2013
             2        011        ur lastname?  abcd         20/10/2013
             3        011        ur number?    abcd         20/10/2013
             4        011        ur email?     abcd         20/10/2013
             5        011        ur name?      xyz          21/10/2013
             6        011        ur lastname?  xyz          21/10/2013
             7        011        ur number?    xyz          21/10/2013
             8        011        ur email?     xyz          21/10/2013
```

i need select query table like

```
        date    empcode       ur name?     ur lastname?      ur number?  ur email? 
     20/10/2013       011           abcd          abcd             abcd        abcd 
    21/10/2013        011            xyz           xyz             xyz        xyz
```

Comment: Search for "SQL Server PIVOT" on this site - there's gotta be **thousands** of questions (and answers!) for this already ....

Comment: thanks  for this term i will read it later, but right now i want exact solution.

Comment: got my solution 

SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT [question_id], [date], [answer]
FROM dsr_ques_ans where empcode='EMP-820485-2'
) AS source
PIVOT
(
 MAX([answer])
 FOR [question_id] IN ([1], [2], [3],[4])
) as pvt;


SELECT date,
      MAX(CASE WHEN question_id= '1'  THEN answer ELSE NULL END) [1],
      MAX(CASE WHEN question_id= '2'  THEN answer ELSE NULL END) [2],
      MAX(CASE WHEN question_id= '3'  THEN answer ELSE NULL END) [3],
     MAX(CASE WHEN question_id= '4'  THEN answer ELSE NULL END) [4]
FROM  dsr_ques_ans 
GROUP BY date